# On new Production Server Some relationships is null after query from mysql database using elequent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cpanel

After find a record from database the relationship properties is null
for example i have a "Booking" and this booking have one record in another entity name "AccommodationBooking" 
after i select the Booking from DB AccommodationBooking is null

but this issue only happens on my new web hosting 
i checked it on 2 different local machines it works well, also i checked it on a hosting which is specially for Laravel it works fine.
but on my new server it is not working

what can make this problem?
Note: this issue only happens on some entities not all of them!

here is my relationships:

```
class Booking extends Model
{
    public function accommodationBooking(){
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Bookings\Accommodation\AccommodationBooking::class,'booking_id','id');
    }
}


class AccommodationBooking extends Model
{
    public function booking(){
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Bookings\Booking::class,'booking_id','id');
    }
}
```

ErrorMessage: Trying to get property of non-object
sample code:

```
return $booking->accommodationBooking->accommodation_booking_ref;
```

i already checked the database, everything is ok, booking is exist in database, foreign key is already defined and everything looks fine.

Comment: please add the error message, the code you tried for fetch result, and sample data which caused error.

Comment: My first test would be to look at the database, and see if the tables are filled the way you expect them to be. Maybe something went wrong when migrating.

Comment: i already checked db also, everything is ok, the record is exist with giving id